# Sub-linear function dominated by continuous sub-linear function is continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $(X,\tau)$ be topological vector space and $g,f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ two sub-linear functions such that:
$$
f(x)\leq g(x)\qquad \forall x\in X
$$
We suppose that $g$ is continuous. Show that $f$ is continuous.

An idea please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

$f(x+h)-f(x) \le f(h)$ and
$f(x) -f(x+h) \le f(-h)$ so $|f(x+h)-f(x) | \le \max(f(h),f(-h)) \le \max(g(h),g(-h))$.